# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel customize - navigation controls outside and black border

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

is there a simple method to do the following changes on the [carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel)?

- navigation controls not as an overlay of the picture
- a black border around the picture (place the nav controls here)
- caption outside too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply an issue of creating your own CSS sheet below the link to the bootstrap stylesheet.

- To move the navigation controls adjust position on: `.carousel-control.right` and `.carousel-control.left`
- Border around image: `.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img`
- Caption: `.carousel-caption`

Look at their CSS through firebug and make your own adjustments.  Again, do not edit the bootstrap CSS itself overwrite it with your own.

Comment: hello, thanks. Can you have a look to this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrR2P/). I didn't get the caption to work?!?